# How to receive a file and send it to different servers

Tags: java, servlets, post, file-upload, web

I have a server that can let user to upload the file. After the user uploads the file, I send a post request to this server
In doGet Method, I did this:

```
  if (path.endsWith("/upload")) {
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.print("<form action=\"/MySelf/upload\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">");
    out.print("<input name=\"file\" type=\"file\" size=\"50\">");
    out.print("<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">");
    out.print("</form>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    }
```

In doPost method, I can do this:

```
if (path.endsWith("/upload")) {
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); 
    String filename = getFilename(filePart);

    //Wanna send this filePart to other servers(for example:127.0.0.1:8888,127.0.0.1:8889 etc.)
}
```

Now, I wanna send this `filePart` to other servers now, how can I use `HttpURLConnection` to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code to send the file to another server.   Thanks to [Mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) for his tutorial on sending post via HttpURLConnection.  Much of this method is derived from that tutorial

```
 // HTTP POST request, sends data in filename to the hostUrl
 private void sendPost(String hostUrl, String filename) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(hostUrl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "testUA");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream remoteStream = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

    byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[1024];
    FileInputStream partFile = new FileInputStream(filename);
    BufferedInputStream bufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream(partFile);

    //read from local filePart file and write to remote server
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while((bytesRead = bufferedStream.read(fileBuffer)) != -1)
    {
       remoteStream.write(fileBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    bufferedStream.close();

    remoteStream.flush();
    remoteStream.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + hostUrl);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    //read server repsonse
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
       response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println("Host responded: ");
    System.out.println(response.toString());

 }
```

Then just call this method from the part of your servlet that accepts the upload data:

```
if (path.endsWith("/upload")) {
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); 
    String filename = getFilename(filePart);

   //send it to a server
   sendPost("http://127.0.0.1:8888", filename);
```

Comment: What if this file is very big? Is there a way that I can avoid converting filePart into String?

Comment: Yes, in the sendPost method, you can read the filePart file a few thousand bytes at a time with `FileInputStream.read()`, and send it to the remote server with multiple `writeBytes()` calls.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to read from a local file and push it to the remote.

Comment: sorry to interrupt you again.. Now we can send file content.. But I also wanna send filename along with its content..How can I do that so that the receiver can know which data are filename, which are file content?

Comment: One easy way, assuming you control the code on the remote server that is reading the posted data.  Reserve 256 bytes or so at the start of the file you are sending to the remote servers, and put the filename in that reserve.  Buffer it with spaces or something to take up the extra space.  On the remote side, read the first 256 bytes off and remove the buffer so just the file name is left.  The first 256 bytes of the stream is filename+buffer, and anything after the first 256 bytes is the file content.

Comment: I find a tricky way, add filename to header like `con.setRequestProperty("File-Name", filename);` :)

Comment: Good idea. That's HTTP specific and a header is a good place for that type of info.